# addEventListener is not a function "Javascript"

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

**My code is:**

```
var isBackgroundApplied = 0;
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("change");

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
 if(isBackgroundApplied === 0){
     document.querySelector("body").style.color = "blue";
     isBackgroundApplied = 1;
 }else{
    document.querySelector("body").style.color = "white";
    isBackgroundApplied == 0;
 }
});
```

**Please help me, the task for the code is to change background color on click.**

Comment: Did you by any chance put this code before the HTML body?

Comment: It is right at the end of the body,the script reference

Comment: See the duplicate - `getElementsByClassName` returns a list (which is clear from any [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) you might care to read...). You can't add an event listener to a list (because it's not a HTML element). You need to loop through the list and add the listener to each one individually.